# Angular filter adding items by $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add products from one list to another. It worked fine before I added a custom filter to it. When I filter the list, ie grade = 2, when I add the first item, it references the first item of the unfiltered list.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="job_product in job_products | filter : customFilter">
      <td>{{job_product.name}}</td>
      <td>{{job_product.grade}}</td>
      <td>{{job_product.slump}}</td>
      <td>{{job_product.flow}}</td>
      <td>{{job_product.last_delivered}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="addProduct($index)">Add</button></td>
    </tr>


$scope.addProduct = function (index) {
    var product = $scope.job_products[index];
    var newProduct = angular.copy(product);
    $scope.products.push(newProduct);
  };
```

Here is the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/2O7cEom1YIWSfGqmAsEb?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just pass not an index but current object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need pass not an index, but current object

```
<tr ng-repeat="job_product in job_products | filter : customFilter">
    <td>{{job_product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{job_product.grade}}</td>
    <td>{{job_product.slump}}</td>
    <td>{{job_product.flow}}</td>
    <td>{{job_product.last_delivered}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="addProduct(job_product)">Add</button></td>
</tr>


$scope.addProduct = function (product) {
    var newProduct = angular.copy(product);
    $scope.products.push(newProduct);
};
```

Comment: Please could you explain why. From what i can understand that shouldn't make any difference. EDIT: oh wait i think i get it, is it because when the list is filtered the `$index` variable does not update for the new list. But keeps the items index in the original list.  I wonder if that's because the global variables are created then ran through any filter chains.

Comment: @ste2425, when you have in list two elements, and filter it(delete first) - you get list with one element, that in source list have index _1_ and in filtered list _0_, and when we pass _0_ we try get by this index from source list

Comment: @Grundy ahh yes its so obvious. We have two lists, the filtered and unfiltered so an items index in one could be different in the other. Thanks